# Как выводить checkbox в зависимости от значения в БД (ajax)

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, checkbox

Понимаю, что абсурдный вопрос, но хотел бы просто увидеть примеры подобной реализации (запрос аякс, вывод чекбокса в зависимости от значения бд)

Comment: ? в зависимости от знаения котороё приходит с бд ставить галку на нужном чекбоксе?

Comment: @Horchynskyi привет, да, именно

Comment: а какоё именно значение приходит?

Answer (score 1):

Даже не знаю как еще можно это написать в виде примера. 
Пояснение: ожидается что сервер плюет JSON объект с полями `error` и `checkbox`. Последний c полем `checked` типа `boolean`.
Не забудьте прогнать код через `babel` или же переписать его не на 6-ом стандарте

```js
function err_handler(err) {console.log(err) /*nevermind*/}

fetch("/my/path/todatabase", {
  method: "get",
  credentials: "include"
}).then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => {
    if (r.error) {
      err_handler(r);
    } else {
      // existing checkbox
      const checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
      
      if (r.checkbox.checked && !checkbox.checked) {
        checkbox.click();
      } else if (!r.checkbox.checked && checkbox.checked) {
        checkbox.click();
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(err_handler);
```